# Can't add google calendar in GNOME calendar app

Tags: calendar, google-calendar

I am using XFCE and Gnome Calendar 3.28.2 (i like how it looks)

So i want to sync my Google Calendar with it and after i click

```
Settings -> Calendars -> Google
```

I see an empty window with `Devices` title, like on screenshot:
[image]

So some wrong window has been opened. May be it depends on XFCE settings ?

I use Ubuntu 18.04 + XFCE + Compiz

Comment: It's trying to open the gnome settings where you manage your online accounts, but I don't know how that would work in xfce.

Comment: Do you have `gnome-online-accounts` package installed? If not, try installing that. You may also need `gnome-control-center`.

Comment: @pomsky, gnome-control-center is already the newest version (1:3.28.2-0ubuntu0.18.04.2).
gnome-online-accounts is already the newest version (3.28.0-0ubuntu2.1).

Answer (score 2):

You could try and force the desktop enviroment to GNOME

```
env XDG_CURRENT_DESKTOP=GNOME gnome-control-center
```